# Magento 2.1 help videos needed

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Need some help from where we can get video help and other tutorial for Magento 2.0 and above.

Can someone please share valuable info or link in this post.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks John for your reply, we are developing small functionality @ product page in which custom measurement of body has to be captured for female clothing line of business. Now we have programming ready but we are stuck with how to insert that data and place the same module in Frontend + how to enable that fct. from backend (first we have to link to product page in bkend). So we are stuck there. Can you help us with some videos or help how can we proceed further. (module is developed but when we add to magento it breakdowns everything, so trying to figure out exactly, what things goes on)

Comment: **John:  you kinda need to know how the module works to explain how to integrate it** >> this is what we need to know that how to integrate it. I can share the what I want into the link, but cannot put it in public place, is there functionality where i can share with you personally?

Comment: We have already done programming similar to this page _TAILORING OPTIONS_ [link](https://www.fabricoz.com/collections/pakistani-clothes-online-all/products/designer-chiffon-collection-9) @John but stuck how to include this as a part of magento code on backend and frontend.

Comment: uhm very good question i don't know how to create chat features, from your link are you saying you want to insert a tailoring options box on product pages? Do you render a PHTML page with the relevant input boxes?

Comment: you're going to want to render an admin panel section using system.xml http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/example-module-adminpage.html a guide to an admin backend is here

Comment: What does your module do, what does it do? does it create an input box that passes the woman's data to somewhere? do you want to be able to read and access the data saved, what specific function does it have? If there's phtml rendered like the tailoring option on the linky ou showed me i can begin to talk you through that

Comment: @John Great Thanks once again for your prompt reply, **What does your module do, what does it do? does it create an input box that passes the woman's data to somewhere?** _Yes_ It send that data to checkout **CART** page. Then it must get stored into db in separate table with having record foreign key attach to every order.  So we don't know where the phtml has to be placed and how to call them and render that. So for this can I get some help or Video Help

Comment: Okay, so you have the DB stuff working correct? you just need to put the filename.phtml inside the page. Can i see the file structure for your module to get an idea of what i'm working with as there's several layers to this, also from what i've seen of this community it's fairly uncommon to share tutorials in video form, there's a real gap in the market i think the community would and could benefit from. Inside your module do you have an ect folder and inside that do you have an adminhtml folder and a system.xml file?

Comment: do you also have a frontend folder inside your view folder? what file structure do you have currently

Comment: @John please see below file structure we have adopted  </br>
app
 code
  Demo
   HelloWorld
    registration.php
    Block
     HelloWorld.php
    Controller
     Index
      Index.php
    etc
     module.xml
     frontend
      routes.xml
    view
     frontend
      layout
       helloworld_index_index.xml
      templates
       HelloWorld.phtml
      web
       css
       image
       js

Comment: I'm sorry man but that's very hard for me to know what that looks like and visualise it, can you take a screenshot and put it in your question

Comment: Here is ![Image](http://www.aristatechnologies.com/tmp/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can get more idea about magento 2 using following link.

http://devdocs.magento.com/videos/

Here you can learn about,

- Create New Page
- Create New Module
- Add New Product Attribute
- Add New Table to Database
- Create Javascript Module

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this doesn't solve our problem or address our issue, what we want is inserting the data and something more.